# Run all jobs on a gitlab ci MR pipeline, even if some don't have a merge_request_event rule, but do not run both MR and branch pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In case the terminology is not standard, here is how I am using the below terms:

- **branch pipeline**: A pipeline that is run when pushing to a branch.
- **MR pipeline**: A pipeline that is run on a merge request, or pushes to a merge request branch.

I want to write a pipeline with two jobs, `job_A` and `job_B`.  `job_A` should run on all pipelines.  `job_B` should run only on merge request pipelines. One solution is to combine the workaround proposed in [issue 194129](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/194129), adding a `workflow` rule of `- if: $CI` with a `merge_request_event` rule, i.e.:

```
image: alpine

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI

stages:
- stage_A
- stage_B

job_A:
  stage: stage_A
  script:
    - echo "Hello from Job A"

job_B:
  stage: stage_B
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  script:
    - echo "Hello from Job B"
```

Now my pipeline runs in full on the MR -- which is what I wanted.  However, two pipelines are being run now, the branch pipeline and the MR pipeline.

I want both `job_A` and `job_B` to run on MR pipelines even though `job_A` doesn't have the `merge_request_event` rule.  But, I only want one pipeline to run when an MR is open -- the MR pipeline.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is found in the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines).

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only:variables. I had the same issue when mixing only/except with rules in one pipeline.

```
job_B:
  stage: stage_B
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  script:
    - echo "Hello from Job B"
```